# notificationcompat

Tags: android-intent, android-notifications, android-context

Necesito saber cuándo un paquete instalado en el teléfono celular puede enviar notificaciones aquí está el código donde se lee las aplicaciones que hay en el teléfono celular y necesito saber si tiene las notificaciones habilitadas a traves de  `NotificationManagerCompat` (`areNotificationsEnabled()`)

```
List<String> paquetenombre = new ArrayList<>();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MESSAGING);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED );
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = context1.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,0);
```